# Custom errorformat for quickfix

Tags: vim, quickfix, errorformat

I have an error message like

```
some text
some text
Error starts ---
error file1
 message1
error file2
 message 2
Error end ---
```

How can I parse only the contents in the error part. I want the `some text` ignored.

Right now for the errorformat I am using

```
%+C\ %.%#,%+A%f:%l:%c:\ error%.%#,%-Z%[%^\ ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
set efm=%-GError\ %.%#\ ---,%Eerror\ %f,%+C\ %.%#,%-G%.%#
```

- `%-GError\ %.%#\ ---,` ignore `Error .* ---` lines
- `%Eerror\ %f,` start multi-line error, get the file name
- `%+C\ %.%#,` continue multi-line error with lines beginning with a space
- `%-G%.%#` ignore all other lines

This works only if you have one error per file, error messages as

```
error file1
 message 1
 message 2
```

will appear as `file1 || message 1  message 2`

Sidenote, for testing, you can put your error message in a file named e.g.  `errorfile.txt`, then `:set errorfile=errorfile.txt` than `:cgetfile` (or `:cg`) will read the `errorfile` and parse it with your `errorformat`.

[`:h error-file-format`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#errorfor)